# Background image doesn't show up

Tags: image

I inserted a background image in blender by checking the background images box and opening an image, but it isn't working. Not in ortho and not in perspective view, i tried all *perfect views*. The first time when i inserted an background image it did work, but now it doesn't work anymore. Here is a screenshot:[image: screenshot of blender]

Comment: And your screenshot is from *perspective* view which won't show background images ever. Nor usual orthographic won't, only preset ones will (Numpad1, Numpad3, Numpad7).

Comment: Images as background only display in the **Preset Ortho* views (Front. Back, Top, Bottom, Left or Right) or on **Camera View**. Perspective view or user Ortho will not display the image.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the Source of the image is either incorrect, or you have changed the file location since making the .blend file.

1. Press Nummpad 5 and then Numpad 1 to get into an orthographic view were the image would normally be view able from
2. Click on the folder icon next to the file location [image: File location]
3. Find where the image is located and accept the location (make sure it is correct) [image: File Location Accept]
4. Your image should now appear in the background of the scene[image: Final Result]